# highchart display lines with the same color

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for a dynamical data, and when I try to display multiple series ( > 10 ), it gives some series with the same color.

For example : 
John series: Blue line | Mary series: Blue Line

How can I fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Please post some code, or a link to a jsfiddle to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more colors as array [color array](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) in the parameter.